# Changing Reference Levels of Categorical Variables Changes Confusion Matrix & Prediction Probabilities

Tags: r, categorical-data, caret, glmnet

I am trying to understand why changing the reference level of a factor changes the results of a model. Consider this example:

```
library(liver)
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
library(dplyr)

data(churn)
head(churn)

# set reference levels
churn$state <- relevel(churn$state, ref = "NE")
churn$area.code <- relevel(churn$area.code, ref = "area_code_408")
churn$intl.plan <- relevel(churn$intl.plan, ref = "yes")
churn$voice.plan <- relevel(churn$voice.plan, ref = "no")

# split into train and test
set.seed(1)
train.index <- createDataPartition(churn$churn, p = 0.8, list = FALSE)
train_churn <- churn[train.index,]
test_churn  <- churn[-train.index,] 

# add class weights
my_weights = train_churn %>%
  select(churn) %>%
  group_by(churn) %>%
  count()

weight_for_yes = (1 / my_weights$n[1]) * ((my_weights$n[1] + my_weights$n[2]) / 2.0)
weight_for_yes
weight_for_no = (1 / my_weights$n[2]) * ((my_weights$n[1] + my_weights$n[2]) / 2.0)
weight_for_no

model_weights <- ifelse(train_churn$churn == "yes", weight_for_yes, weight_for_no)

# tuning grid
myGrid <- expand.grid(
  alpha = 0, 
  lambda = seq(0,1,0.01)  
)

set.seed(1)
mod_1 <- train(churn ~
                 state +
                 area.code +
                 intl.plan +
                 voice.plan,
               data = train_churn,
               method = "glmnet",
               tuneGrid = myGrid,
               weights = model_weights)

mod_1
```

Tuning parameter 'alpha' was held constant at a value of 0
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 0 and lambda = 0.8.

```
prediction <- predict(mod_1, newdata = test_churn)
confusionMatrix(prediction, test_churn$churn)
```

[image]

I also look at a single new prediction

```
new_data = data.frame(state = c("CA"),
                      area.code = c("area_code_510"),
                      intl.plan = c("yes"),
                      voice.plan = c("no"))

predict(mod_1, newdata = new_data, type = "prob")
```

[image]

Now I restart R, set new reference levels, and rerun all the code. This is the output

```
# set new reference levels
churn$state <- relevel(churn$state, ref = "OR")
churn$area.code <- relevel(churn$area.code, ref = "area_code_415")
churn$intl.plan <- relevel(churn$intl.plan, ref = "no")
churn$voice.plan <- relevel(churn$voice.plan, ref = "yes")
```

Tuning parameter 'alpha' was held constant at a value of 0
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were alpha = 0 and lambda = 0.62.

[image]

[image]

I expected the lambdas to change, but I did not expect the confusion matrix or classification probabilities to changes. Is this normal?

Comment: All of the accuracy measures you are using have terrible properties.  For some alternatives see [here](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue).  And if you need to weight or balance data not sampled with sampling weights, you IMHO are going down the wrong path.

Comment: @FrankHarrell What do you recommend for classifying imbalanced data? I am aware of subsampling techniques (up, down, SMOTE, rose), using class weights (as I'm doing here), cost-sensitive training, and adjusting the classification threshold.

Comment: None of those methods respect the sample characteristics, and all of them will result in classifications that will not work as well on real data with all of its natural imbalances.  The need for balancing/weighting in this setting was invented by the machine learning world and not from those trained in statistics.  Proper probability models/machines respect the raw data and will yield results that apply to new data streams that are similar to the training data stream and sometimes even when the new data are not similar.  See https://academic.oup.com/jamia/article/29/9/1525/6605096

Comment: Also see https://hbiostat.org/blog/post/mlconfusion/ and note that probability machines defer the decision (aka classification) to later.  Based on the predicted probabilities and lost/cost/utility function you can make optimum decisions, and also elect to make no decision when the probability is in the gray zone, i.e., collect more data before making a decision on hard-to-call observations.